# ERC-20 balances

Tags: erc-20, tokens, balances

How do I get balances of all the ERC-20 tokens for a wallet address

Irwing Tello

Comment: Please clarify your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Balance for an ERC-20 token can be fetched using the `balanceOf` function of that particular token's smart contract. But hundreds and thousands of tokens are out there, so doing this process for all of them is not ideal.

There are various data providers who have this data indexed and provide an easy way to fetch them, one of them is QuickNode.

You can get all the ERC-20 tokens a wallet address holds using QuickNode custom RPC [qn_getWalletTokenBalance](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/qn_getWalletTokenBalance_v2)

To use this, enable the [Token and NFT API bundle Add-on](https://marketplace.quicknode.com/add-on/token-and-nft-api-v2-bundle) on your QuickNode Ethereum endpoint, then use this script:

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "id": 67,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "qn_getWalletTokenBalance",
  "params": [{
    "wallet": "0xd8da6bf26964af9d7eed9e03e53415d37aa96045"
  }]
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("QUICKNODE_URL_HERE", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Check this video and learn how to create a token balance app: https://youtu.be/ReW6Giid43w

If you prefer a powerful GraphQL interface, you can check out quickNode's Graph API which I covered in my answer here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/151886/122985

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear, are you referring to an ERC20 token?
If that is the case, use the "balanceOf" function defined in the standard.
eg:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract TokenBalance {
    function getTokenBalance(address tokenAddress, address userAddress) external view returns (uint256) {
        IERC20 tokenContract = IERC20(tokenAddress);
        return tokenContract.balanceOf(userAddress);
    }
}
```