# How to get ERC 721/1155 and ERC-20 data?

Tags: erc-20, nft, erc-721, erc-1155

How do I get all the NFTs (ERC-721 & 1155) and Tokens (ERC-20) for a wallet address? Is there an API for this?

Irwing Tello

Comment: If you are affiliated with QuickNode you should add a disclaimer to the question. It isn't against SE policies to ask and answer the question yourself, but you should add a disclaimer for your affiliation.

Comment: Hi @Ismael, I am not affiliated with QuickNode, I marked QuickNode's answer as valid because it was the one that solved my problem quickly and it was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this data using the `balanceOf` function of the token smart contracts. But doing this for each token and NFT is not a nice experience.

Using a solution like [QuickNode](https://www.quicknode.com/), which provides two solutions for this would be way easier.

**The First option is using [QuickNode custom RPCs](https://marketplace.quicknode.com/add-on/token-and-nft-api-v2-bundle)**

- [qn_getWalletTokenBalance](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/qn_getWalletTokenBalance_v2) - for ERC-20 balances
- [qn_fetchNFTs](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/qn_fetchNFTs_v2) - for ERC-721 balances

To use this, enable the [Token and NFT API bundle Add-on](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/qn_fetchNFTs_v2) on your QuickNode Ethereum endpoint.

Here's an example in ethersv6:

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");
(async () => {
  const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("QUICKNODE_RPC_URL");
  const walletAddress = "ADDRESS_TO_BE_QUERIED";
  const coins = await provider.send("qn_getWalletTokenBalance", [
    {
      wallet: walletAddress,
    },
  ]);

  const nfts = await provider.send("qn_fetchNFTs", [
    {
      wallet: walletAddress,
      page: 1,
      perPage: 10,
    },
  ]);

  console.log(coins,nfts);
})();
```

**The second option is [QuickNode Graph API](https://www.quicknode.com/graph-api)**

By using the following GraphQL query:

```
query Query($address: String!) {
  ethereum {
    walletByAddress(address: $address) {
      tokenBalances {
        edges {
          node {
            contract {
              address
              decimals
              name
            }
            totalBalance
          }
        }
      }
      walletNFTs {
        edges {
          node {
            nft {
              externalUrl
              name
              metadata
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the wallet address as a variable:

```
{
  "address": "WALLET_ADDRESS_GOES_HERE"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the information you are looking for using [Moralis API](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm).

Here is an example of getting all the NFTs using moralis.

```js
const Moralis = require("moralis").default;

const runApp = async () => {
  const { EvmChain } = Moralis.EvmUtils;

  await Moralis.start({
    apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
    // ...and any other configuration
  });

  const address = "0xd8da6bf26964af9d7eed9e03e53415d37aa96045";

  const chain = EvmChain.ETHEREUM;

  const response = await Moralis.EvmApi.nft.getWalletNFTs({
    address,
    chain,
  });

  console.log(response.raw);
};

runApp();
```

And this is what the results will look like.

```json
    {
      "token_address": "0xc84ac7bf8b4cec60d82fb93dfb61b03d5e4acd39",
      "token_id": "1953",
      "amount": "1",
      "owner_of": "0xd8da6bf26964af9d7eed9e03e53415d37aa96045",
      "token_hash": "28d043249272e630cf598fe80b789491",
      "block_number_minted": "17481420",
      "block_number": "17482230",
      "contract_type": "ERC721",
      "name": "BoringApes",
      "symbol": "BORING",
      "token_uri": "https://ipfs.moralis.io:2053/ipfs/QmSapUjjycSnYXg2RS8HopNQX1pkDzYoQnECGwjPeASMZp/1953.json",
      "metadata": null,
      "last_token_uri_sync": "2023-06-14T23:25:30.517Z",
      "last_metadata_sync": "2023-06-14T23:26:17.905Z",
      "minter_address": null,
      "possible_spam": false
    },
    {
      "token_address": "0x4b59cc984b5ad15515d19d65aa39bd3e1dc98d59",
      "token_id": "7",
      "amount": "1",
      "owner_of": "0xd8da6bf26964af9d7eed9e03e53415d37aa96045",
      "token_hash": "592d4b5d222b9c926df5c1fe3aa131e0",
      "block_number_minted": "17476789",
      "block_number": "17481819",
      "contract_type": "ERC1155",
      "name": "Uniswap Airdrop Recipient",
      "symbol": "Noox Distribution Protocol",
      "token_uri": "https://ipfs.moralis.io:2053/ipfs/QmXTawe96xK99kL3mA7RrzUmAuWT15QY3BTsi4WgH1SDWT/7",
      "metadata": "{\"name\":\"Noox : Uniswap Airdrop Receipent\",\"description\":\"Owning this badge indicates that the user has received uniswap airdrop. Each badges are non-transferable NFTs. For more information, visit https://www.noox.fund\",\"external_url\":\" https://www.noox.fund\",\"image\":\"ipfs://bafybeifftr7cbh6rkssevgvprvwea32b6asw7m4tthxirkouj5fn6fvsce\",\"attributes\":[{\"trait_type\":\"category\",\"value\":\"DeFi\"},{\"trait_type\":\"website\",\"value\":\"noox.fund\"}]}",
      "last_token_uri_sync": "2023-06-14T07:46:29.024Z",
      "last_metadata_sync": "2023-06-19T12:56:45.947Z",
      "minter_address": "ERC1155 tokens don't have a single minter",
      "possible_spam": false
    },
```

You can find a guide here: [How to get all the NFTs owned by an address](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/how-to-get-all-nfts-owned-by-an-address)

For the ERC20 Tokens Balance, you can use the following example

```js
const Moralis = require("moralis").default;
const { EvmChain } = require("@moralisweb3/common-evm-utils");

const runApp = async () => {
  await Moralis.start({
    apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
    // ...and any other configuration
  });

  const address = "0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d";

  const chain = EvmChain.ETHEREUM;

  const response = await Moralis.EvmApi.token.getWalletTokenBalances({
    address,
    chain,
  });

  console.log(response.raw);
};

runApp();
```

And this is the expected result

```json
  {
    "token_address": "0x709b5a3c7a22250981869a8080a354de919f821e",
    "symbol": "DMON",
    "name": "DogeMon",
    "logo": null,
    "thumbnail": null,
    "decimals": 9,
    "balance": "500000000000000",
    "possible_spam": true
  },
  {
    "token_address": "0x2df495dfc4a24064acc573e9ec9f5bd509b42e40",
    "symbol": "GAMEBOY",
    "name": "Nintendo Gameboy",
    "logo": null,
    "thumbnail": null,
    "decimals": 18,
    "balance": "1500000000000000000000000000",
    "possible_spam": true
  },
  {
    "token_address": "0xb2ea9527bf05bc3b73320a1ec18bd4f2fe88d952",
    "symbol": "OP",
    "name": "Optimism",
    "logo": null,
    "thumbnail": null,
    "decimals": 18,
    "balance": "767387143779415173800484933",
    "possible_spam": true
  },
```

You can find a guide for erc 20 token balance here: [How to get all ERC20 tokens owned by an address](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/how-to-get-all-erc20-tokens-owned-by-an-address)

Disclosure: I work at Moralis